# How to perform copy paste operation of a line drawn by mouse on Group container?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I am working on a project where i need to perform copy and paste operation.I draw a line with the help of mouse on Group container.Now i want to paste it.Please provide me the solution...........

Comment: I have drawn a line with the help of mouse.and i am able to select line.but when i perform copy paste i am not able to do that.please help me

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define a data structure for your chart(for example, you define a `Line` with properties `start`(Point), `end`(Point), `width` and `color`)

Next, you need to create a UI to render the `Line` inside the `Canvas` (group container). The ui is responsible for providing interactions such as resize, change color etc. as well. It can render a lot of `Line` instances according to their properties (`start`, `end`, `width` and `color`)

Now, your copy and paste are easy.

Just duplicate the selected `Line` instance and tell the UI to render the duplicated instance.